# Need Oracle Query Tune for order by

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, sql-order-by

I have two tables:

```
METHOD_TYPES
---- ----------------
 ID   Methods_Type
---- ----------------
 1    public
 2    ALL_Methods
 3    private1235678
 4    social


METHOD_TABLE
-------- ----------------- ----------
 Ser_ID   Ser_Method_Type   Emp_Name
-------- ----------------- ----------
 1        (null)            AAAA
 2        (null)            BBBB
 3        All_Methods       Rama
 4        social            Raja
 5        private12345678   Rakesh
```

I used the below query for the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Methods_Type, 1, 10) AS disMisType
  FROM METHOD_TABLE MET
  LEFT JOIN METHOD_TYPES TRMT
    ON MET.Ser_Method_Type = TRMT.Methods_Type
 ORDER BY (NLSSORT(MET.Ser_Method_Type, 'NLS_SORT=binary_ai')) DESC NULLS FIRST;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
(null)
All_Methods
(null)
social
private12345678
```

But I need to order all the nulls first.
Kindly provide the exact query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the data you provided - and adding in the extra columns, I get:

```
with method_types as (select 1 id, 'public' methods_type from dual union all
                      select 2 id, 'ALL_Methods' methods_type from dual union all
                      select 3 id, 'private1235678' methods_type from dual union all
                      select 4 id, 'social' methods_type from dual),
     method_table as (select 1 ser_id, null ser_method_type, 'AAAA' emp_name from dual union all
                      select 2 ser_id, null ser_method_type, 'BBBB' emp_name from dual union all
                      select 3 ser_id, 'All_Methods' ser_method_type, 'Rama' emp_name from dual union all
                      select 4 ser_id, 'social' ser_method_type, 'Raja' emp_name from dual union all
                      select 5 ser_id, 'private12345678' ser_method_type, 'Rakesh' emp_name from dual)
select substr(trmt.methods_type,1,10) as dismistype,
       met.*,
       trmt.*
from   method_table met
       left join method_types trmt on (met.ser_method_type = trmt.methods_type)
order by (nlssort(met.ser_method_type, 'NLS_SORT=binary_ai')) desc nulls first;

DISMISTYPE                         SER_ID SER_METHOD_TYPE EMP_NAME         ID METHODS_TYPE  
------------------------------ ---------- --------------- -------- ---------- --------------
                                        1                 AAAA                              
                                        2                 BBBB                              
social                                  4 social          Raja              4 social        
                                        5 private12345678 Rakesh                            
                                        3 All_Methods     Rama
```

which is not what your expected output shows, but it does maybe explain why you see nulls apparently out of order in your results - you're selecting the trmt.methods_type column, but ordering by the met.ser_method_type column. If there aren't any rows in the method_types table matching those in the method_table, then of course you will see nulls, but because there *IS* a value in the method_table, they may well be displayed *after* rows that do have a value.

Perhaps all you need to do is to change the column being selected 
from `substr(trmt.methods_type,1,10)`
to `substr(met.ser_method_type,1,10)`

or change the order clause
from `nlssort(met.ser_method_type, 'NLS_SORT=binary_ai')`
to `nlssort(trmt.methods_type, 'NLS_SORT=binary_ai')`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your query is not working, but you can have a more explicit `order by`:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN MET.Ser_Method_Type IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         NLSSORT(MET.Ser_Method_Type, 'NLS_SORT=binary_ai') DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a CASE Column only for order:

```
select SUBSTR(Methods_Type,1,10)AS disMisType,
       SUBSTR(CASE WHEN Methods_Type IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE Methods_Type END ,1,10) AS disMisTypeORDER
FROM   METHOD_TABLE MET
       LEFT JOIN METHOD_TYPES TRMT
         ON MET.Ser_Method_Type = TRMT.Methods_Type
ORDER BY disMisTypeORDER
```